# how to use Codemirror.on('change') to save only changed using PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, codemirror

I need use the changes only, not all the text, to provide server resources and service user.
see [Code Mirror: Get Text Around Changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19744118/code-mirror-get-text-around-changes)

HTML:

```
<textarea id="code">script.js</textarea>
```

JavaScript:

```
var id = document.getElementById("code");
var options = {mode:'javascript'};
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(id, options);
editor.on("change",function(cm,change){
    $.ajax({
        url:'update.php',
        method:'POST',
        data:{
            save:true,
            file:'script.js',
            update:change
        },
        success:function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['save']) && $_POST['save'] === true){
    if(isset($POST['file']) && file_exists($POST['file'])){
        $file = file_get_contents($POST['file']);
        if(isset($POST['update']) && !empty($POST['update'])){
            $change = @json_decode(@json_encode($_POST['update']));
            //here how to use data from $change to update file script.js?
        }
    }
}
```

!!

Comment: There is quite a good amount of work necessary to fulfill your request to transfer only changes of the text document and not the full text itself. You have to check if text has been added, deleted or modified. Additionally if the user is doing a lot of changes, you will have network traffic for each "onchange" event - that's each keystroke. if the file itself isn't huge, you wont have saved anything after a few keystrokes only. Rethink your aproach.

Comment: no problem with real time communication "RTC"
in this ask i use ajax for example only. in fact i use nodejs with socket.io for send any changes.